# Remove entire array from foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm trying to filter and remove arrays that match a specific value. I'm getting JSON from an API which is then being decoded through PHP usng json_decode. It displays perfectly fine but it comes up with values I don't want.

JSON file = https://pastebin.com/raw/7yW1CEdu

I'm using the following foreach statement which works and displays data for every stat that I need (I've stripped it for the purpose of focusing on the removing of the array):

```
<?php foreach($json['response']['data'] as $item) { 
      
    $newarray = array_filter($item['competitionName'], function($var) {
        return ($var != 'Junior SS Premiership Zone 3');
    });
  }
?>
```

This is how I want it to look compared to how it currently looks - https://gyazo.com/d8654cc939dba9e0e52f06e66f489323

What's wrong with my array_filter code? I want it to remove any array that specifically states that:
`"competitionName":"Junior SS Premiership Zone 3"` so any data in that array will not be processed in the foreach.

Thanks!

Comment: `$item['competitionName']` isn't an array, it's a string.

Comment: Maybe this is where I'm getting confused. I want to remove the entire array if a string is equal to 'Junior SS Premiership Zone 3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$item['competitionName']` is a string, not an array of strings. I think what you want is:

```
$data = array_filter($json['response']['data'], function ($item) {
    return $item['competitionName'] != 'Junior SS Premiership Zone 3';
});
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // display the data
}
```

Or don't bother with the filter, just check for it in the main loop and skip it.

```
foreach ($json['response']['data'] as $item) {
    if ($item['competitionName'] == 'Junior SS Premiership Zone 3') {
        continue;
    }
    // process the item
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much! I see where I went wrong now. It was a pretty simple fix. What if I want to excude a second competitionName such as ```Senior Competition Example XX``` ?

Comment: `if ($item['competitionName'] == 'Junior SS Premiership Zone 3' || $item['competionName'] == 'Senior Competition Example XX')`

Comment: Or you could use a series of `if` statements just like the first one. Or you could put all the names to exclude in an array, and use `in_array()`

Comment: Sorry what if I wanted to sort them by date too? So it says 2019, 2020 etc. Would I run another function so it sorts from 2020 at the top down to 2018 at the bottom? uSort i think was the way

Comment: Yes, `usort` is what you want. You would do that before the loop.